# Visual Studio project and asset folders

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Web Application project where the users can upload images to the site. We intend on storing these images in the file system, somewhere off the web root (for example, ~/Resources/Images). The users should be able to view the images in the browser by the Url (eg site.com/Resources/Images/image1.jpg)

My issue is, that creating a folder called Resources allows it to appear in my Visual Studio project, and hence anything i upload becomes visible in that folder in VSS, and could potentially be checked in (which I don't want, as the files are data, not code, and are volatile).

I am using Cassini to view the site as we build. I thought about IIS and using a virtual folder, and will use it if I have no choice. But, is there anyway to make the folder visible to Cassini, without it affecting my project.

I fully appreciate I may not have explained this properly, so feel free to look puzzled.

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Web Application Project you have to specify which file & folders are part of the project - they don't just appear. If you are using a Web Site Project, then the folders will get picked up when you open the web site and the files will become part of the project.

I assume you know the potential security issues involved with allowing the users to upload files into a location under the web root of your application?